# CakePhp 3.2.2. Date string saving into database in UTC format

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to save string '1989-10-10' to database as date. My local timezone is Europe/Moscow.

First I added timezone to bootstrap.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
```

Then in controller

```
$model = TableRegistry::get('model');
$entity = $model::newEntity(); 
$entity->birthday = '1989-10-10';
$model->save($entity);
```

And as result in database this date looks like 1989-10-09. 
Somehow cake understands my current timezone as Moscow and try to convert it to UTC. This is static date and shouldn't be converted.

Comment: The date doesn't look changed to me.

Comment: Which version of cake do you use? 
Have you set the same time zone as mine?

Comment: I haven't tested anything, I'm just referring to the dates that you are showing here, they are perfectly equal.

Comment: For previous version of cake (3.1.7) It worked fine. Just after update to 3.2.2 problems occur. If I enter a datetime string it works fine too, problem just with date.
[code]
object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

 'time' => '1987-10-09T00:00:00+00:00',
 'timezone' => 'UTC',
 'fixedNowTime' => false
}

Answer (score 0):

CakePhp has created a new version 3.2.3 where is this bug seems to be solved.

```
Date::parseDate() now correctly handles timezones. (@lorenzo)
```

here is more information: http://bakery.cakephp.org/2016/02/21/cakephp_3016_3111_323_released.html